# How to backup SQL Server database files directly?

Tags: sql-server

My Windows 10 installation is corrupted and I can't login anymore. I'm using Ubuntu Live to copy all the files to an external HDD. Is there a way i can copy the database files directly then restore them after i install Windows and SQL server again?

Comment: Stop SQL Server and copy mdf and ldf files.

Answer (score 1):

Use restore files and filegroups instead of restore the database. If all files (.bak/.ldf/.mdf) are valid it should work fine